# How to resize a UITableViewCell after it has already been rendered?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to programmatically resize the height of a UITableViewCell after it has already been rendered. Since the cell has already been rendered, I can't use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

How can I resize the cell after it has already been rendered?

Comment: So how did you manage to do it in the end?

Comment: @Nico I think I just reloaded the entire table data. I've been wanting to try the reload rows with animation method mentioned in the answer, but haven't had a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must re-calculate in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and after that you must reload this cell or call `tableView` `reloadData`.

Example you want resize cell at row 4. And you have button tap to it to resize, you can implement like this

```
func resizeCell() {
     self.indexReload = NSIndexPath(section: 0, row:4)
     self.heightYouWant = heightYouWant
     self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([self.indexReload], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}
```

And `heightForCellAtIndexPath` you have to implement like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     if index == self.indexReload {
         return self.heightYouWant
     } or {
         //calculate normal as you want
     }
}
```

It is my idea. Hope this help!